# Is it possible to require for a certain time complexity in a concept

Tags: c++, time-complexity, c++-concepts

Accordigly to [cppreference named requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req) a lot of algorithms requires to perform in certain time complexity (linear, constant). So i wonder is it possible with c++20 concepts to write a constraint for it, and if not is it even considered to be a good idea to be able to check for something like that?

```
template <class T>
concept linear = requires (T val) {
    // magic here
}
```

Comment: Anyone who invents any kind of a turing-complete process for determining the complexity of some arbitrary algorithm is going to be a shoe-in for a Nobel prize. Until that happens the only way to do that would be if a template, itself, specified its complexity in some well-defined fashion. Then a concept can be defined based on that. Unfortunately, nothing of this sort is defined by any of the C++ libraries algorithms. Your only option would be to compile an exhaustive, explicit list of C++ contains and algorithms, and use that in the concept.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: The question does not say anything about any computed or automated process for determining complexity. It could just be an assertion in the declaration of the function, provided by humans. Complexity requirements are stated in the C++ standard. And there is no Nobel Prize for mathematics or computer science.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

In general, C++ abstract machine model does not have any concept of time or steps really.

No, the standard does not specify any time complexities, the only defined complexities are in terms of observable operations - comparisons and such. There is never any true *time*, step, or instruction complexity for any function in C++ and there cannot be.

The minimal requirements by the Standard on running a C++ program as set by [intro.abstract](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.abstract#6):

- Accesses through volatile glvalues are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
- At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to one of the possible results that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
- The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input.
  What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.

AKA *as-if* rule - if you cannot tell the difference, compiler can do anything it wants and time or number of executed instructions do not count as observable effects.

Comment: Ok, understood, but can we e.g take the code using some kind of compile-time reflection (maybe in future standarts it will be added) and count operations based on information recieved by this introspection, can we then tell wether algorithm behaves better or worse than another?

Comment: Re “There is never any true time, step, or instruction complexity for any function in C++ and there cannot be”: The containers library does say its complexities are stated in numbers of operations on contained objects. (I am looking at draft N4849.) But complexities elsewhere in the standard are said to be in time generally (or space, whichever is applicable). If your argument is the “as if” effect of the “minimal requirements” clause nullifies stated complexity requirements elsewhere, I would say that is an unwarranted mechanical interpretation of that clause…

Comment: … Clearly the numerous statements of required complexities in various places in the standard are intended to have effect. Otherwise there would be no point in stating them. Their intent is to require conforming implementations to meet (or exceed) those complexity guarantees regardless of the “minimum requirements” clause. The intro.abstract clause is, as it says, a description of semantics, not performance—the observable semantic behavior must be the same as that of the abstract machine. That clause is not intended to nullify performance requirements.

Comment: @David you can already programmatically compare the complexity of code, Google benchmark does this. https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md#asymptotic-complexity. Incorporating it into the language is another matter. Doing so in a way that doesn’t add eons to your compile time is yet an even other matter. I don’t see anyone asking for this, But if it’s something you’re really keen on, I think you should get the ball rolling.